# Middleclick leads to page back in Firefox

Tags: firefox

when I middleclick, on a link, it opens it in a new tab, which is the wanted behavior. But sometimes, I miss the link by a few dots which leads in firefox going a page back.
In Windows that behavior does not occur. How can I change this, so nothing happens, when middleclicking anywhere except of links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, it seems that you changed a setting.

According to the default [setup](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mouse-shortcuts-perform-common-tasks) a middleclick in some area should not go backwards in history.

Sometimes I accidentally paste an url with a middle click somewhere in a page... Could that explain the behaviour you see?

Comment: Ah you are right. Its not going back to the last page, its going to the link in the cache. A workaround I found is to go to about:config and set middlemouse.contentLoadURL to false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the UX nightly(i think i recall encountering it with ubuntu's own firefox too) and this behaviour appears to be default, though i'm not sure quite why, googling i found a post blaming it on middlemouse.contentLoadURL being set true by default on linux, which i personally think is a bit stupid to begin with, but the puzzling thing is that, while it's suggested to be interactions between clipboard.autocopy and middlemouse.contentLoadURL, it occurs with urls which were never selected or manually copied, which seems to go against the latter's stated function. Even more odd is that, having toggled middlemouse.contentloadurl to false and back again the behaviour has disappeared, which makes this situation look very buggy indeed.

This was mainly a problem for me as my over-excitable trackpad sends middle click events at random from time to time and mozilla's the only browser than navigates away from the current page when these occur. This behaviour is neither predictable nor expected for 95% of typical ubuntu users, or 99.9% of ubuntu's target market.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/887873

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you are suggesting as an answer here.